# How to execute to concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor.map() with function params?

Tags: python, concurrency, concurrent.futures

I have a list of iterables and I'd like to execute a function on all of them in a given chunk size. Per the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html, I know I can do something like

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=numberOfThreads) as executor:
    futures = {
        executor.map(fn, iterables, chunksize=someChunkSize)
    }
```

Where `fn` is defined as:

```
def fn(obj):
    #do something and return something
```

But what if `fn` takes multiple params:

```
def fn(constantParam1, constantParam2, obj):
    #do something and return something
```

Is there now no way to use this function with `executor.map` due to the additional params?

Alternatively, for the `submit` function, defined according to the docs `submit(fn, *args, **kwargs)`, one can clearly pass the params as so:

```
executor.submit(fn, constantParam1, constantParam2, obj): obj for obj in iterableOfObj
```

but it doesn't seem to support `chunksize`.

How can one either:

1. pass additional params to `fn` in `executor.map`?
2. set a chunksize for the `executor.submit`?

Answer (score 0):

I find it easiest to define an intermediate worker that expands the arguments

```
def _call_fn(args):
    return fn(*args)
```

Comment: Can you explain or show how you'd use this? Assuming `iterableOfObj` is a list of length 10, something like 
`fn_args = [param1]*10, [param2]*2, iterableOfObj \n map(_call_fn, fn_args)`
Is this your approach?